# Why memory of spark executor keep growing?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I submit my code to a standalone cluster running on one node. The node have 16GB memory and 8 core CPU.

I noticed that the executor memory keeps growing. Very slow but really growing. Eventually the memory of executor will exceed the setting I specified and cause the program hang there.  With some error like :

```
16/05/09 19:32:32 ERROR ContextCleaner: Error cleaning broadcast 12242
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTime
```

The submit command I use is here:

```
./bin/spark-submit   --master spark://ES01:7077 --executor-memory 4G --num-executors 1 --total-executor-cores 1 --conf "spark.storage.memoryFraction=0.2" ./mycode.py   1>a.log 2>b.log
```

The workload is not heavy. A few kb data will be calculated during each batch interval. And my executor memory is setting to 4GB.

The code is very simple so I will post here also in case there might be anything inappropriate.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row, HiveContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.window import Window


def getSqlContextInstance(sparkContext):
    if ('sqlContextSingletonInstance' not in globals()):
        globals()['sqlContextSingletonInstance'] = HiveContext(sparkContext)
    return globals()['sqlContextSingletonInstance']


def top_n(df, groupby_column, agg_column, ):
    df_agg = df. \
        groupBy(['tag', 'interface', groupby_column]). \
        agg(func.sum('pkts').alias('pkts'), func.sum('bits').alias('bits'))

    windowSpec = Window. \
        partitionBy(df_agg['tag'], df_agg['interface']). \
        orderBy(df_agg[agg_column].desc())

    rank = func.dense_rank().over(windowSpec)

    top_n_agg = df_agg. \
        select(df_agg['tag'], df_agg['interface'], df_agg[groupby_column], df_agg['pkts'], rank.alias('rank')). \
        filter("rank<=2")
    top_n_agg.show()


def process(time, rdd):
    if rdd.isEmpty():
        return sc.emptyRDD()

    sqlContext = getSqlContextInstance(rdd.context)

    # Convert RDD[String] to RDD[Row] to DataFrame
    parts = rdd.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
    rowRdd = parts.map(lambda p: Row(
        tag=p[0], in_iface=int(p[1]), out_iface=int(p[2]), src_ip=p[3], dst_ip=p[4], src_port=int(p[5]),
        dst_port=int(p[6]), protocol=p[7], ip_dscp=p[8], flow_direction=p[9], pkts=int(p[10]), bits=int(p[11])))

    df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd)

    dataframe_ingress = \
        df.filter(df['flow_direction'] == 0). \
            select(df['tag'], df['in_iface'].alias('interface'), df['src_ip'], df['dst_ip'], df['src_port'],
                   df['dst_port'], df['protocol'], df['flow_direction'], df['pkts'], df['bits'])
    dataframe_ingress.cache()

    #########################################
    # top N
    #########################################
    top_n(df=dataframe_ingress, groupby_column='protocol', agg_column='pkts')
    top_n(df=dataframe_ingress, groupby_column='protocol', agg_column='bits')
    top_n(df=dataframe_ingress, groupby_column='src_ip', agg_column='pkts')
    top_n(df=dataframe_ingress, groupby_column='src_ip', agg_column='bits')
    top_n(df=dataframe_ingress, groupby_column='dst_ip', agg_column='pkts')
    top_n(df=dataframe_ingress, groupby_column='dst_ip', agg_column='bits')

    dataframe_ingress.unpersist()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dataDirectory = '/stream/raw'

    sc = SparkContext(appName="Netflow")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 15)

    lines = ssc.textFileStream(dataDirectory)
    lines.foreachRDD(process)

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Are there any more error messages? Have you look at the spark UI to check the workers stderr?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I will check the stderr next time I hit error. But I guess that may not help. Because if it is memory leak. Then the only error will be out of memory. And the reason of memory leak will not be logged

Comment: It doesn't look like an OOM to me. Not from the exception you posted.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov But from the top command. You can find that the memory usage of executor keeps growing. Until there is no free memory in the OS